# Pretty urls with Htaccess show product name in the url but call the product with the id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I trying to do with the htaccess, something like that.

```
http://www.domain.com/product/fussball-in-munich/
```

But the link of the menu navigation will be like this,

```
<a href="product.php?id=10">Fussball</a>
```

I'll call to the product by the ID, but i want to display in the url the product name,

I make this with my htaccess but doesnt work how i want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^angebot/([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+)$ /dev/product.php?product_id=$1 [NC]

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

My php file

```
 if (isset($_GET['product_id'])){

$product_id = strip_tags($_GET['product_id']);
getProductsById($product_id);


}
```

the Function

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE id='$product_id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$count = $result->num_rows;
    if ($count === 1){
        echo "<div class='container mt50'>";

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            echo '<strong>This Product has been found in the database </strong>' .$row['product_name'];


                }
                echo "</div>";


    }else{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your htaccess file doesn't know anything about the relationship between a product id or its name, that's all in your DB. You'll have to code all of this up in your php file.

in the htaccess file, you can only have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^angebot/([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+)$ /dev/product.php?product_name=$1 [L]
```

then all the rest of the logic has to be coded into php:

1. check if "product_name" is set
2. check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']` has `product.php` in it
3. strip out the stuff that made the name pretty (replace "-" with spaces)
4. lookup in the db for the product with the given name and get the ID
5. get the ID and call `getProductsById($product_id)`

Then the other way around (redirect the browser if they access the ugly URL):

1. check if "product_id" is set
2. check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']` has `product.php` in it
3. if it does, someone requested directly your product ID
4. use the ID, do a db lookup for the product name, clean up the product name so that it doesn't look ugly (maybe spaces get changed to "-")
5. redirect the browser to the new pretty URL