# Create better URL - .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My URL is looking now like this:

> localhost/en/products/bear-toys/bear.php?id=26123

And i need to looks like this:

> localhost/en/products/bear-toys/bear/26123

or if i can get title of that product and store into URL:

> localhost/en/products/bear-toys/bear/blue-bear.php

I know there is solution with `.htaccess` but im not good one in `.htaccess`. So any kind of help will be good. Thanks all

Comment: Is there always 4 elements to your query string or do you want to have different lengths after products/ ?

Comment: I need to have this `en/products/product-category/sub-category/` then product and best solution for me now is to get title of product @blupointmedia

Comment: It might help to show what you've got in your `.htaccess` file so far and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: In my htaccess i have only what `blupointmedia` post as answer @showdev

Comment: I see, okay. To generate more answers, it may help [do a little research and make an attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise people might feel like they are just writing free code. Here are some ideas about how to get an item's id from its name: [show product name in the url but call the product with the id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22417005/924299) and [mod_rewrite with name replacing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218043/924299).

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything after products you can do something like this in htaccess and in PHP. products.php can be the page you want to write to to accept the param(s)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*)$ product.php?lang=$1&q=$2 [L,NE]
```

and this in PHP

```
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$params = explode('/', $_GET['q']);

echo $lang . '<br>';
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201231/discussion-on-answer-by-blupointmedia-create-better-url-htaccess).

Comment: Thanks @SamuelLiew